# Spree Zone#zone_members.empty? returns incorrect value in spree 1.3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I noticed weird thing developing `Spree` application (I'm using Spree 1.3.2):

Spree uses model called `Zone`. `Zone` is associated with `zone_members`, like this:

```
has_many :zone_members, :dependent => :destroy, :class_name => "Spree::ZoneMember"
```

Strange part begins here, in rails console:

```
zone = Spree::Zone.first
zone.zone_members.empty?
# => true
zone.zone_members
# => []
zone.zone_members.reload.empty?
# => false
zone.zone_members
# => [#<Spree::ZoneMember id: 4914820, zoneable_id: 13, zoneable_type: ...
```

What's interesting this problem doesn't occur in Spree 1.3.3. 
Apart from Spree, I use Rails 3.2.14 (or Rails 3.2.13 - the same result) and Ruby 1.9.3. 
Does anybody know why does it happen?

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that this was a bug that was fixed between Spree 1.3.2 and Spree 1.3.3. I highly recommend using 1.3.3, as that is the latest stable gem release from that branch and probably contains more than just that fix.